# detected a division by zero in animated.divide node in react native ios

Tags: react-native

I get the above error in react native 0.49. I'm using Animated for simple animation. and I don't use Animated.divide, I don't get the why I get this error , here's my code:

```
_ChangeAvatarScale() {
    if (ProfileStore.avatarScaleStatus) {
        Animated.sequence([Animated.timing(ProfileStore.avatarScale, {
            toValue: 0.7,
            duration: 120,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }),
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(ProfileStore.avatarPosition, {
                toValue: -20,
                duration: 120,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }),
            Animated.timing(ProfileStore.cameraPickIcons, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 100,
                useNativeDriver: true
            })
        ])
        ]).start();
        ProfileStore.avatarScaleStatusChange();
    }
    else {
        Animated.sequence([Animated.timing(ProfileStore.avatarScale, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 120,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }),
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(ProfileStore.avatarPosition, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 120,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }),
            Animated.timing(ProfileStore.cameraPickIcons, {
                toValue: -350,
                duration: 100,
                useNativeDriver: true
            })
        ])
        ]).start();
        ProfileStore.avatarScaleStatusChange();
    }
}
```

and the mobx store :

```
 @observable avatarScale = new Animated.Value(1);
@observable avatarPosition = new Animated.Value(1);
@observable avatarScaleStatus = true;
@action avatarScaleStatusChange(){
    this.avatarScaleStatus = !this.avatarScaleStatus;
}
@observable cameraPickIcons = new Animated.Value(-350);
```

and I get this problem only in ios, the related file is RCTDivisionAnimatedNode.m

Comment: Do you have any interpolate's or anything similar in your code?

Comment: yeah I use react native text input effects for form, in the source code it uses interpolate, but for the code that I wrote, I don't use interpolate

Comment: The issue you are having is about supplying that library with 0, and it uses it to divide in some place.

Comment: so what if there's a need to use zero?

Comment: You need to use it when you are sure you won't be dividing by it :) It requires you to test each one of them sadly.

Comment: got it, thank you for your time